# How to use use Google+ API in Windows app?

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-store-apps, google-plus-signin

Actually, I haven't worked with any API like Facebook, Twitter and/or Google (also its products) etc...

Think you have 2 textboxes and a button in your (windows app) page. When you entered your login details and clicked button you should logged in to your Google account. So, I have read the Googles official documentation about this. I also read [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps). But didn't achieve anything...

#### Edit:

I didn't tried any code about this. Because, I couldn't understand that how it works...

P.S I'm not developing Asp.Net WebForms, MVC or any web related things. I'm developing app for Windows Store.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show us your code and what didn't work for you?

Comment: @Sylverac I edited question.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth) is some information about Google's Identity platform. And [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed_applications) is a .NET guide on how to use it. This should get you started.

**EDIT:** The above are links to Google's Identity API documentation with guides on how to implement the API in various languages (including the .NET guide I linked). It is too much to post the contents of those pages here so instead, use the search terms "google api authentication" on google and you should find the same results I did.

Comment: Thanks. This article is very uselful. But I want to check that user exists or not using user entered details. How and where I can use user entered information such as email and password ?

EDIT:
Or how can I send the user details to Google Servers?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11094382)

Comment: @WaiHaLee I made an edit to address your concern.